# How can I refresh Chrysanthemum's in the garden?

Tags: plant-care, flowers, chrysanthemum

My plants will flower in a month or two but they have dead leaves on the stems already.

Comment: Hello Rosalie,  Please share with us some pictures.   I would love to see your plant, to easier diagnosis the problem.   Can you also tell me a little more about your care.  Like what type of lighting.  Is this an indoor 'florist mum' or outdoor plant.  How long have you had it?  Any information you can share will be appreciated.  Cheers.

Comment: They should not have dead leaves up the stems if they've not yet flowered - are your plants in pots? If not, when did you plant them out (assuming they are outdoors)? Otherwise, a photo would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

The leaves are easy to remove.   The plant is putting all of it's energy in to making flowers. These plants have been bred to be prolific bloomers.  This process is very energy consuming.   You can help it by fertilising.  Use a balance fertiliser that contains macro & micro nutrients.  The macro nutrients are normally located on the front of the package as three numbers like 10-10-10.  On the side or back of the package it will list all the nutrients available for your plants.  It should have a list that includes the macro nutrients, Nitrogen, Phosphorous & Potassium and should include other nutrients like manganese & iron.   Good Luck.